# Why is __new__ not being called on my Python class?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a class defined like so:

```
class Client():
    def __new__(cls):
        print "NEW"
        return cls

    def __init__(self):
        print "INIT"
```

When I use it, I get the following output:

```
cl = Client()
# INIT
```

`__new__` is not being called.  Why?

Comment: if you already know the answer why do you want to ask ??

Comment: @avasal: besides the rep points? as a memento of some sort ?

Comment: I marked it as "answer my own question" when submitting, so I assume it gets placed in the community wiki and has no points attached to it.  For some reason, I still have to wait 2 days to assign the answer as correct though.

Comment: He probably has learned it the hard way and wants to share it with us, instead of waiting until someone else asks something similar.

Comment: Also, note that there are some quite enlightening comments in the self-answer. Also again, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467/156615) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12519/156615).

Comment: Yeah answering your own question is encouraged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having read your answer, I improve it with

```
class Client(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        print "NEW"
        return super(Client, cls).__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self):
        print "INIT"
```

so that `c = Client()` outputs

```
NEW
INIT
```

as intended.

Comment: You should really be using `super` if you're writing new-style classes.

Comment: @ecatmur Normally I do so. But does it also work here? As `cls` is not an instance of `Client`, but a subclass, it was unclear to me if it works.

Comment: No, doesn't work: with `return super(Client, cls).__new__()` I get a `TypeError: object.__new__(): not enough arguments`. `return super(Client, cls).__new__(cls)` works, but is it wise to do so?

Comment: That's what http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__ recommends: `super(currentclass, cls).__new__(cls[, ...])`

Comment: @ecatmur Ok, changed the answer. Having to duplicate the `cls` looks unclean to me, but it works...

Comment: This is a better answer as it explains how to handle the result of `__new__` correctly.  In my actual code I was passing the instance of an entirely different class out (so that it could act as a sort of "direct proxy") and thus had no need to deal with any of the super calling.

Answer (score 7):

Classes must inherit explicitly from `object` in order for `__new__` to be called.  Redefine `Client` so instead it looks like:

```
class Client(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        print "NEW"
        return cls

    def __init__(self):
        print "INIT"
```

`__new__` will now be called when used like:

```
cl = Client()
# NEW
```

Note that `__init__` will never be called in this situation, since `__new__` does not invoke the superclass's `__new__` as it's return value.

Comment: Actually, the reason `__init__` will be invoked is that `__new__` returns something that is not an instance of `Client`. It returns the class `Client` itself, which is an instance of `type`.

Comment: How else can you create an instance of `Client` without requesting that `object` does so via `__new__`?

Comment: Normally you can't; instances are (usually) ultimately created by `object.__new__`. But you could return an existing object, or call some other unrelated code that itself invokes `object.__new__`. But my point was that the rule about whether `__init__` gets invokes is solely about whether `__new__` returns an instance of the class. It has nothing to do with whether `__new__` contains a superclass call; the machinery that decides whether to invoke `__init__` or not doesn't even know this.